# How can I find merges with unexpected conflicts in git?

Tags: git, merge

In the following example, I produce a merge at the head of master which is "strange" -- it changes a file under which there was no conflict. Git doesn't seem to like telling me that I've done so.

```
git init test
cd test
seq 1 5 > file1
git add file1
seq 6 10 > file2
git add file2
git commit -m root
git branch branch
sed -i 's/7/8/' file2
git commit -a -m '7++'
git checkout branch
sed -i 's/7/6/' file2
sed -i 's/3/4/' file1
git commit -a -m '7--; 3++'
git checkout master
git branch oldmaster
git merge branch
git checkout master file1
git checkout branch file2
git commit
```

Obviously the process of producing this problem is unusual, but assuming I'm not the one who created it, how can I find it? git log is unhelpful; it doesn't even show which of the conflicts I picked:

```
git log -p --graph
*   commit cde4ac55b4c60d5c5c7f36bae9d9cc34689b20c1
|\  Merge: 8689e18 f42deb9
| | Author: David Buckley <bucko@gambitresearch.com>
| | Date:   Tue Dec 9 12:29:51 2014 +0000
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'branch'
| |     
| |     Conflicts:
| |             file2
| |   
| * commit f42deb9971ca05afbff11bb5dcc77650585c990b
| | Author: David Buckley <bucko@gambitresearch.com>
| | Date:   Tue Dec 9 12:29:51 2014 +0000
| | 
| |     7--; 3++
| | 
| | diff --git a/file1 b/file1
| | index 8a1218a..6234030 100644
| | --- a/file1
| | +++ b/file1
| | @@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
| |  1
| |  2
| | -3
| | +4
| |  4
| |  5
| | diff --git a/file2 b/file2
| | index 1e1140b..63f0f17 100644
| | --- a/file2
| | +++ b/file2
| | @@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
| |  6
| | -7
| | +6
| |  8
| |  9
| |  10
| |   
* | commit 8689e183d785af50dd2f92e3d7bed3b62507447f
|/  Author: David Buckley <bucko@gambitresearch.com>
|   Date:   Tue Dec 9 12:29:51 2014 +0000
|   
|       7++
|   
|   diff --git a/file2 b/file2
|   index 1e1140b..6f1177a 100644
|   --- a/file2
|   +++ b/file2
|   @@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
|    6
|   -7
|   +8
|    8
|    9
|    10
|  
* commit bb2a50a7164ffe79a2fc26d0008ca4fe26b07442
  Author: David Buckley <bucko@gambitresearch.com>
  Date:   Tue Dec 9 12:29:51 2014 +0000

      root

  diff --git a/file1 b/file1
  new file mode 100644
  index 0000000..8a1218a
  --- /dev/null
  +++ b/file1
  @@ -0,0 +1,5 @@
  +1
  +2
  +3
  +4
  +5
  diff --git a/file2 b/file2
  new file mode 100644
  index 0000000..1e1140b
  --- /dev/null
  +++ b/file2
  @@ -0,0 +1,5 @@
  +6
  +7
  +8
  +9
  +10
```

At issue is that the merge commit at the head reverts the change to file1, but git log doesn't indicate that this has taken place, or even that this merge is interesting at all.

git blame can't see the reversion (it claims all of file1 can be blamed on the initial commit), even when I merge master into branch instead of the reverse.

I can find it *in this case* by forcing diffs with each parent using '-m', but this is next to useless where a lot of work has been done on both branches prior to the merge -- the unusual change will be swamped by legitimate changes from both sides, and every 'normal' change made in every parent will be repeated.

Clearly, 'git merge' could find the issue here, as the commit has differs from the parents in a way that merge alone would not have suggested. It feels like the diff outputting is formatted using only the commit in question and all of its parents as source information. I would prefer that it also took into account the merge base of all parents -- and in the case of no merge base, offered output similar to '-m'.

I can get something close to what I want with:

```
diff -u <(git diff oldmaster..master) <(git diff $(git merge-base oldmaster branch)..branch)
--- /proc/self/fd/11    2014-12-09 13:01:44.576808417 +0000
+++ /proc/self/fd/12    2014-12-09 13:01:44.576808417 +0000
@@ -1,10 +1,21 @@
+diff --git a/file1 b/file1
+index 8a1218a..6234030 100644
+--- a/file1
++++ b/file1
+@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
+ 1
+ 2
+-3
++4
+ 4
+ 5
 diff --git a/file2 b/file2
-index 6f1177a..63f0f17 100644
+index 1e1140b..63f0f17 100644
 --- a/file2
 +++ b/file2
 @@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
  6
--8
+-7
 +6
  8
  9
```

And:

```
diff -u <(git diff branch..master) <(git diff $(git merge-base oldmaster branch)..oldmaster)
--- /proc/self/fd/11    2014-12-09 13:02:05.680455766 +0000
+++ /proc/self/fd/12    2014-12-09 13:02:05.680455766 +0000
@@ -1,14 +1,14 @@
-diff --git a/file1 b/file1
-index 6234030..8a1218a 100644
---- a/file1
-+++ b/file1
+diff --git a/file2 b/file2
+index 1e1140b..6f1177a 100644
+--- a/file2
++++ b/file2
 @@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
- 1
- 2
--4
-+3
- 4
- 5
+ 6
+-7
++8
+ 8
+ 9
+ 10
```

However, the second output is obviously somewhat clumsy.

Can I persuade git to perform this logic for me?

Comment: I don’t really understand your question. Does `git show cde4ac55` help?

Comment: Also, the merge isn’t really suspicious; it works as intended: A merge will look at the overall changes of all branches since their common base and then will try to apply both changes at once. A conflict only happens if Git is unable to do so on its own (usually if multiple changes happen in the same place in the same file).

Comment: Is `git blame` able to correctly identify the origin of the new lines as he merge commit?  I would expect it to be able to, and this is basically what you're asking ("where did these changes come from?") but I haven't tried it.

Comment: poke: Nope; git show has the same behaviour as git log -- it displays either nothing (because each changed part is accounted for by exactly one parent), or far too much.

Comment: poke: The merge "smells bad" as it reverts a patch in a different branch to the one which was intended to be merged. It's not the conflict that's at issue, it's git's diff output deleting the important changes. There was a change to file1 which is listed in git log, but is not present in the master, and there appears no way of getting git log to express this.

Comment: Edward: 'git blame' claims that the '3++' change was never made -- the entire blame for file1 is the root commit. This isn't /unreasonable/ in the direction illustrated, but if the merge was master->branch instead, one might expect the merge to be to blame for the '3' being present, as the merge reverted it being changed to '4'.